# ソーラン節の「[男度胸]{おとこどきょう}。。。」という一節

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

The line in Soran Bushi that says

> [男度胸]{おとこどきょう}なら　[五尺]{ごしゃく}のからだ
> どんと乗り出せ　波の上　チョイー

What does it literally mean? I think I know the words, but I can't understand what they mean from those meanings...
I thought it means "Men, if you are brave, your five feet of body..." Then I don't know what どんと乗り出せ means-  どん like the sound, and I'm lost as to the meaning of 乗り出せ, and why it's imperative.

Answer (score 1):

It is an admonition, not a strict imperative (command). It says that a man of 五尺 (five feet) must be brave, to 乗り出せ (*ride out* or perhaps *lean out*) 波の上 (over the waves).

I feel that the tenor of the command is more like Horace Greeley's published quote of J. B. Soule's hortatory advice, "Go west, young man, go west." Not "do it now" but "aspire to do it."

Perhaps a better analogue (note: *not* a translation of the above, just a parallel mood of exhortation):

> Make no little plans. They have no magic to stir men's blood and probably themselves will not be realized. — [Daniel Burnham, Chicago architect](http://www.ontko.com/pub/rayo/burnham.html)

Comment: What about the "Don"?

Comment: You can find it in jisho https://jisho.org/search/donto

Answer (score 1):

- どんと is defined by 大辞林 as  思い切り and 力いっぱい, so it indicates a strong will/decision.
- 「乗り出す」means "to go and ride (over the waves)".
- チョイー is a variation of ちょっと (though im not totally sure if this is the case here).

*"If you are a man of bravery, with your five Shaku long body: Go ride in all your will, over the waves, come on!"*

As a side note, 乗り出す can also mean "to lean forward", usually seen as "身を乗り出す"